# Inside Grid view Image Button is not firing using an ASP.NET Web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Inside Grid View Image Button is not firing using an ASP.NET Web form. If I will use ASP Button, then working Button and easy adding.

Below is my design Code of grid view Button.

```
<FooterTemplate>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" ImageUrl="~/Imgs/grid_add.png" ToolTip="click here to add" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Team_involved_directly" />
 <%-- <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="AddNew" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Team_involved_directly" ToolTip="click here to add"  />--%>
</FooterTemplate>
```

If I will use above commented button then working fine, but Image Button only giving Issue. And I also used `!Page.IsPostBack`in my page load.

Comment: Are you add to gridview event "OnRowCommand"?

Comment: yes added like OnRowCommand="Gridview1_RowCommand". @mww

Comment: Other commands fire this event just this button not ?

Comment: asp button is working but asp image button is not working and not firing, the why asp button working. @mww

Comment: If i will use above commented button and remove image button then working, I need image button only. @mww

Comment: Try add also OnCommand event to your ImageButton and set same method which fire grid oncommand event.

Comment: I did not understand. @mww

Comment: It works fine when I tried it. The only difference I can think of is that the `ImageButton` uses javascript to do a PostBack while a `Button` does a form post directly. Check your console for errors, maybe there is a problem with `Team_involved_directly` validation group.

Comment: Ya, Its java script conflict issue and that the reason ImageButton not firing. @VDWWD

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried 'OnClick' method for button tag?

Comment: why I should use OnClick and I am using CommandName="AddNew" na. @Keshav_Nandhan

Comment: sorry I was mistaken,so you are using like event.commandname==""?

Comment: I will also try @MMK

Comment: Yes. @Keshav_Nandhan